# How can i make a JPanel that has the same size as the imported image?

Tags: java, image, jpanel

I want to make a JPanel that automatically has the same size as the image that's being imported, so if i click on the image, the JPanel know's exactly where the click was on the image.

I don't need to resize the image/JPanel.

How do i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a JScrollPane with a fixed size wrapping the JPanel, and on loading a new image, resize the panel. One might use a JLabel for displaying the image.

```
JLabel imageLabel = new JLabel();
JScrollPane imageScrollPane = new JScrollPane(imageLabel);
add(imageScrollPane);

imageLabel.setIcon(...);
imageLabel.setSize(...);
```